# 'int' is not subscriptable in Django, it was in pure python

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import a json feed into my database. I first wrote a pure python script and then edited it to use Django's database functions.

```
def getListOfProperties():
    if getLastModifiedTimestamp() != 0:
        url = URL + "?from_date=" + str(getLastModifiedTimestamp())
    else:
        url = URL
    resp,cont= client.request(url, "GET")
    results = json.loads(cont)

    try:
        properties = results['properties']
    except KeyError, e:
        return "Geen panden in Max-immo"

    for property in properties:
        if checkIfPropertyInDBList(id=property['id'])== 0:
            #do something
        else:
            #do the other thing

    if len(properties)!=0:
        addPropertiesDetail()


getListOfProperties()
```

In the pure python script, the function **checkIfpropertyDbList** looks like this:

```
import settings
def checkIfPropertyInDBList(id=0):
    db = settings.db()
    cur = db.cursor()
    if id==0:
        cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mi_import")
    else:
        cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mi_import WHERE id = %s" % id)
    return cur.fetchone()[0]
```

The **settings** module looks like this:

```
###settings.py
import MySQLdb

def db():
    return MySQLdb.connect(
        host= "localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="*****",
        db="*****",
    )
```

When running the script in the Terminal, it works just fine. The problem is, I need the script to be integrated in a Django site deployed on the Google App Engine, so i adjusted above function to use Django's built-in database module:

```
from django.db import connection, DatabaseError

def checkIfPropertyInDBList(id=0):
    cur = connection.cursor()
    if id==0:
        cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mi_import")
    else:
        cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mi_import WHERE id = %s" % id)
    return cur.fetchone()[0]
```

This however gives me an **TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable**.

Here is the complete traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: localhost:8088/cron/importAll/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'south',
 'app']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django_1_3/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/project/app/cron.py" in lookupProperties
  180.     getListOfProperties()
File "/Users/username/PycharmProjects/project/app/cron.py" in getListOfProperties
  169.             if checkIfPropertyInDBList(id=property['id'])== 0:

Exception Type: TypeError at /cron/importAll/
Exception Value: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like an error in the `result` dict. The property is an `int` when `checkIfPropertyInDBList` is being called. Print out `properties` and it should help reveal the error.

Comment: can you share the value of `properties` object?

Comment: You get the error for `property['id']`. I'd say, `property` is not what you think it is.

Comment: It looks like "property" is an int.  As far as I can tell, this is a problem with json, not Django.  It's possible that you have imported a different json library so things don't work the same?  Have you tried "print property" before line 169?

Comment: properties would be a variable referencing to:
`[{u'creatie_datum': 1030611060,
u'id': 1,
u'wijziging_datum': 1349171874},
{u'creatie_datum': 1031298180,
u'id': 2,
u'wijziging_datum': 1194874135},
{u'creatie_datum': 1032872760,
u'id': 3,
u'wijziging_datum': 1163498036},
{u'creatie_datum': 1032872760,
u'id': 4,
u'wijziging_datum': 1195726181},
{u'creatie_datum': 1032876180,
u'id': 5,
u'wijziging_datum': 1267179716},
`

Comment: @CarlF. that might be i used built-in json module in the terminal. In django i used the simplejson module.

The simplejson module worked in the past, in other scripts.

Comment: Can you do a `print property['id']` just before referencing it? There could be some corrupt data which is throwing an error